# Picasso Main Errored

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to use Picasso Android library but i'm not able to get it working.

For starting, i am trying the simplest of the things:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_view);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(this).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(this).setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(mImageView);
}
```

the activity layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The view remains completely red.
If i set a resource in the view via setImageResource, it correctly displays.

The only relevant clue that something went wrong is a message saying:

Picasso: main errored

but i can't understand why.

I would happily paste more logcat output but it breaks the code block and becomes unreadable.

Here's a pastebin: [main errored log](http://pastebin.com/JVQQAAnj)

I believe there's something trivial i am doing wrong.

Comment: this layout is the content of `activity_basic_view.xml`?

Comment: yes, it's the content of that layout file

Comment: you have internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Your `fill_parent` should be replaced with `match_parent` in API 8+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To download images from the internet, you will need the INTERNET permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```